# friend finder app in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to develop an application in android using eclipse .
This application is like finding the friend location and directions using android mobile .

Now my idea to do this is in three steps :
1. tracing the location of your friend if he is having the GPS connectivity .
2. then putting that location in Google maps with your location .
3. Google maps gives us the directions and this way we get it .

But now I want to know if thats possible . if yes ,l any tutorials for these work or something which might help me.

Surbhi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you and your friend both download your app, this would be possible.  Instead of tracking a user of your application, I would recommend simply obtaining their location when it is needed.  I would recommend reading some of the Android documentation on [obtaining the user location](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html).  Maybe a better place to start would be the [Android framework fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html).